# Adding a custom task in NopCommerce, return list of daily bestsellers

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I'm working on creating a custom task in NopCommerce that lists most sold products of the day and show this data in the admin panel. E g lists all products that has been sold and order them by number of sold.

Iv'e found some code that runs a BestSeller report which is great, allthough this method is quite large and i'm uncertain which part i actually need in order to display the list of bestsellers. Also the method for bestsellers is a "virtual IList and the execute method is void.

This is the code for bestsellers:

```
class MostSoldProductsTask : ITask
    {


        private readonly IRepository<Order> _orderRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<OrderProductVariant> _opvRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<Product> _productRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<ProductVariant> _productVariantRepository;

        private readonly IDateTimeHelper _dateTimeHelper;
        private readonly IProductService _productService;





        public virtual IList<BestsellersReportLine> BestSellersReport(DateTime? startTime,
            DateTime? endTime, OrderStatus? os, PaymentStatus? ps, ShippingStatus? ss,
            int billingCountryId = 0,
            int recordsToReturn = 5, int orderBy = 1, int groupBy = 1, bool showHidden = false)
        {
            int? orderStatusId = null;
            if (os.HasValue)
                orderStatusId = (int)os.Value;

            int? paymentStatusId = null;
            if (ps.HasValue)
                paymentStatusId = (int)ps.Value;

            int? shippingStatusId = null;
            if (ss.HasValue)
                shippingStatusId = (int)ss.Value;


            var query1 = from opv in _opvRepository.Table
                         join o in _orderRepository.Table on opv.OrderId equals o.Id
                         join pv in _productVariantRepository.Table on opv.ProductVariantId equals pv.Id
                         join p in _productRepository.Table on pv.ProductId equals p.Id
                         where (!startTime.HasValue || startTime.Value <= o.CreatedOnUtc) &&
                         (!endTime.HasValue || endTime.Value >= o.CreatedOnUtc) &&
                         (!orderStatusId.HasValue || orderStatusId == o.OrderStatusId) &&
                         (!paymentStatusId.HasValue || paymentStatusId == o.PaymentStatusId) &&
                         (!shippingStatusId.HasValue || shippingStatusId == o.ShippingStatusId) &&
                         (!o.Deleted) &&
                         (!p.Deleted) &&
                         (!pv.Deleted) &&
                         (billingCountryId == 0 || o.BillingAddress.CountryId == billingCountryId) &&
                         (showHidden || p.Published) &&
                         (showHidden || pv.Published)
                         select opv;

            var query2 = groupBy == 1 ?
                //group by product variants
                from opv in query1
                group opv by opv.ProductVariantId into g
                select new
                {
                    EntityId = g.Key,
                    TotalAmount = g.Sum(x => x.PriceExclTax),
                    TotalQuantity = g.Sum(x => x.Quantity),
                }
                :
                //group by products
                from opv in query1
                group opv by opv.ProductVariant.ProductId into g
                select new
                {
                    EntityId = g.Key,
                    TotalAmount = g.Sum(x => x.PriceExclTax),
                    TotalQuantity = g.Sum(x => x.Quantity),
                }
                ;

            switch (orderBy)
            {
                case 1:
                    {
                        query2 = query2.OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalQuantity);
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    {
                        query2 = query2.OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalAmount);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("Wrong orderBy parameter", "orderBy");
            }

            if (recordsToReturn != 0 && recordsToReturn != int.MaxValue)
                query2 = query2.Take(recordsToReturn);

            var result = query2.ToList().Select(x =>
            {
                var reportLine = new BestsellersReportLine()
                {
                    EntityId = x.EntityId,
                    TotalAmount = x.TotalAmount,
                    TotalQuantity = x.TotalQuantity
                };
                return reportLine;
            }).ToList();

            return result;
        }



        public void Execute()
        {


            throw new NotImplementedException("Return something");
        }
```

I also have to return this list via the "Execute" -method that is implementing the ITask interface. My best guess is to have one method creating the list of bestsellers and have have the "Execute method implementing the first one and return it.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you misunderstood the purpose if `ITask` interface. `ITask` is used to run some background, non-UI tasks, so you can never get it to 'return' the list in admin panel.

What you want to do, instead, is to run it periodically and save the data in some custom table. Then use it

Comment: Thanks. Not exactly sure how i would go about archieving that though